# Tomcat server not supporting asynchronous controller api

Tags: rest, api, tomcat, asynchronous, spring-boot

I am developing a REST API and want to make it as an asynchronous Rest Controller,
So my Controller is below:

```
@RestController
@Async
public class ApiController {
    List<ApiObject>  apiDataList;   

    @RequestMapping(value="/data",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ApiObject>> getData(){                                       
        List<ApiObject> apiDataList=getApiData();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ApiObject>>(apiDataList,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @ResponseBody   
    public List<ApiObject>  getApiData(){
        List<ApiObject>  apiDataList3=new List<ApiObject> ();
        //do the processing
        return apiDataList3;
    }
}
```

Then in the Spring boot Application class I created as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync

public class APIApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(APIApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

After that in the server.xml I tried to add the Nio Connector like below:

```
<Connector maxThreads="1000" port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nioprotocol"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

But when I run this the tomcat is not to able to start:

It shows the error
[image: Error]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a standalone tomcat?

Comment: I have deploying mostly all web applications in Stand Alone Tomcat Server  only.

Comment: Add error logs as text please. I think you have permissions issue with /opt/apache-tomcat****